# Question about ring with matric structure

Tags: matrices, ring-theory

Show that for any $p$ $\in$ R, a ring with unit identity, and $i \neq j$, $1+pe_{ij}$ is ivertible in $M_{n}(R)$ with inverse $1-pe_{ij}$.

Mainly I wander ask what $M_{n}(R)$ is and how does $1+pe_{ij}$ looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M_n(R)$ is the ring of $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $R$.

Example (for $n=3$)

$$1+pe_{1,2}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & p & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$$

and its inverse

$$1-pe_{1,2}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & -p & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$$

Proof  in general:

$$(1+p e_{i,j})(1-pe_{i,j})=1-p^2 e_{i,j}^2=1,$$ because of $e_{i,j}^2=0$ for $i \neq j$.

Comment: Would you mind if I would ask how to solve the question? I try but I fail in constructing a inverse for the other.